# dynamodb tutorial

Tags: sdk, amazon-ec2, lamp, amazon-dynamodb

Can anyone recommend a good soup to nut tutorial on how to set up an environment on an Amazon EC2 environment where I can test and play around with dynamoDB?

I want to start with 
vanilla 64 bit Amazon EC2 ami
table already setup in dynamo DB with no data imported

I want to end up with:
A fully configured LAMP Environment on the 64bit Amazon EC2
SDK installed and configured
able to read and write to/from the DynamomDB table

I have tried to follow the steps to set up the SDK and I am getting nowhere, and there is no explanation for the errors I am getting. I feel like I am chasing my tail from one tutorial to another and google is not my friend tonight, hopefully stackoverflow will come through again. Thanks again for you help in advance keeping me from becoming mr. furious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start, I suggest making a simple app that uses DynamoDB from your desktop using the Java AWS SDK (http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/). The SDK has some simple examples for access DynamoDB (https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-java/tree/master/src/samples/AmazonDynamoDB).

Then once you get your app the way you want you can start an EC2 instance and work on deploying your app to it. There really isn't anything special required to get an EC2 instance to access DynamoDB.